# How to add scrollview to included layout in android?

Tags: android

I have a textfield aligned at top and another at bottom. I have included another layout in between these two. I want to scroll only the included layout keeping top and bottom fields fixed. Give me solution to scroll included layout between two fixed views at top and bottom...waiting

Answer (score 2):

Put ScrollView in between TextField and put included layout in ScrollView.

```
<TextView .../>
<ScrollView...>
<LinearLayout>

Your Include Layout

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<TextView.../>
```

Comment: It worked...thanks for easiest solution